# Advanced installer powershell inline script APPDIR empty

Tags: powershell, advanced-installer

I am using Advanced installer. I want to move a directory from the installation directory to another directory. The problem is that the APPDIR variable is empty. How can I do to recover the installation directory? APPDIR is always empty.
Thank you.

```
<#
.NOTES
  "pwsh.exe" is run if required version is greater or equal to 6, otherwise
  "powershell.exe" is invoked by default
#>

#Requires -version 3
Param($appDir)

$programFilesDir = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles")

echo $appDir >> "D:\install.log"
echo "$appDir_Installation\Java" >> "D:\install.log"
echo "$programFilesDir" >> "D:\install.log"

Copy-Item -Path "$appDir_Installation\Java" -Destination "$programFilesDir" -Recurse
```

[image]

Comment: Please paste in your code so it is readable.

Comment: i updated the post

Comment: How are you calling it

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot on this I would recommend you to use a message box into your code to display the value of the $appDir variable. Just  to make sure its value is really empty. At a first glance the APPDIR (installation folder) property is correctly passed to your script and it shouldn't be empty.

You can add this code into your script and see what it is the value passed to your $appDir variable:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($appDir)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your APPDIR variable is empty because you need to pass the name too in the "Parameter value" option.

As you can read in documentation [Getting a property value into a script](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/custom-actions-list.html#script-inline), you need to configure like this:

```
-AppPath "[APPDIR]"
```

Also, you need to update the Param() block of the script, which must be on the first line, as follows:

```
Param($AppPath)
```

[Check this script example which works, it is used to copy the files to another folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC4BK.png)